# How to reshape 1D RGB to 2D RGB image in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, reshape

Suppose I have 1D RGB array of the following structure:

```
I = [r1 r2 ... rN; g1 g2 ... gN; b1 b2 ... bN];
```

where

```
N = H*W;
```

ans H and W are height and width of the picture respectively.

How to reshape it to colored image format HxW, which is represented by 3D matrix so that

```
I2(1,1,1) = r1
I2(1,1,2) = g1
I2(1,1,3) = b1
I2(2,1,1) = r2
I2(2,1,2) = g2
I2(2,1,3) = b2
...
I2(H,W,1) = rN
I2(H,W,2) = gN
I2(H,W,3) = bN
```

(if I am correct thinking that normal 1D -> 2D reshape works by columns)

**UPDATE**

This reshaping can be done the following way

```
R = I(1,:);
R = reshape(R,H,W);

G = I(2,:);
G = reshape(G,H,W);

B = I(3,:);
B = reshape(B,H,W);

I2 = cat(3, R, G, B);
```

Can it be done shorter, with one `reshape` call for example?

Comment: What you have for I in this example isn't 1D in Matlab. Is your actual array just a 1D array of numbers where the first third is your R values, second third your G values, and last third your B values?

Comment: Obviously, from Matlab point of view, it is 2D array of numbers. From logical point of view it is 1D array of pixels, where all pixels are laid out along Matlab's 2nd dimension and pixel components are laid out along Matlab's 1st dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what you're looking for is: `reshape(I', H, W, 3)`